# Reaching an appropriate balance between performance and scalability in a large database

Tags: database, database-design, nlp, data-mining

I'm trying to determine which of the many database models would best support probabilistic record comparison. Specifically, I have approximately 20 million documents defined by a variety of attributes (name, type, author, owner, etc.). Text attributes dominate the data set, yet there are still plenty of images. Read operations are the most crucial vis-a-vis performance, but I expect roughly 20,000 new documents to insert each week. Luckily, insert speed does not matter at all, and I am comfortable queuing the incoming documents for controlled processing.

Database queries will most typically take the following forms:

- `Find documents containing at least five sentences that reference someone who'a a member of the military`
- `Predict whether User A will comment on a specific document written by User B, given User A's entire comment history`
- `Predict an author for Document X by comparing vocabulary, word ordering, sentence structure, and concept flow`

My first thought was to use a simple [document store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) like, like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), since each document does not necessarily contain the same data. However, complex queries effectively degrade this to a file system wrapper, since I cannot construct a query yielding the results I desire. As such, this approach corners me into walking the entire database and processing each file separately. Although document stores scale well horizontally, the benefits are not realized here.

This led me to realize that my granularity *isn't* at the document level, but rather the *entity-relationship* level. As such, [graph databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) seemed like logical choice, since they facilitate relating each word in a sentence to the next word, next paragraph, current paragraph, part of speech, etc. Graph databases limit data replication, increase the speed of statistical clustering, and scale horizontally, among other things. Unfortunately, ensuring a definitive answer to your query still necessitates traversing the entire graph. Even still, indexing will help with performance.

I've also evaluated the use of relational databases, which are very efficient when designed properly (i.e., by avoiding unnecessary normalization). A relational database excels at finding all documents authored by User A, but fails at structural comparisons (which involves expensive joins). Relational databases also enforce constraints (primary keys, foreign keys, uniqueness, etc.) efficiently--a task with which some NoSQL solutions struggle.

**After considering the above-listed requirements, are there any database models that combine the "exactness" of relational models (*viz.*, efficient exhaustion of the domain) with the flexibility of graph databases?**

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, just a discussion.

The database you are talking about is a large database.  You don't mention the nature of the documents, but newspaper articles are typically in the 2-3k range, so you are talking about hundreds of gigabytes of raw data.

If query performance is an issue, you are talking about a large, rather expensive system.

Your requirements are also quite complex, and not likely to be out-of-the-box.  I would be thinking of a hybrid system.  Store the document metadata in a relational database system, so you can quickly access them with simple queries.  You can store the documents themselves in the database as blobs.

Some of your requirements can be met with text-add ins on relational databases.  So, simple searching is feasible using inverted index technology.  That handles the first of your three scenarios.

The other two are much more challenging.  The third ("predict an author") can probably be handled by having a parallel system that stores author information, summarized from the documents when they are loaded.  Then it is a question of comparing a document to the author, using simple statistical analysis (naive Bayesian, anyone?).

The middle one is tricky, but it suggests yet another component for managing comments on documents.  Depending on the volume, this may be easy or hard.

Finally, how changing are the requirements?  Do you really know what the system should be doing?  Or will the functionality be radically different once you get it up and running?